# Meteor deploying on Ubuntu: bcrypt_lib.node: invalid ELF header

Tags: ubuntu, meteor

I keep getting `bcrypt_lib.node: invalid ELF header` in my Meteor app's log. It is deployed on Ubuntu 14.04.

As a common solution, I have passed `--architecture=os.linux.x86_6` option when building the app, and the app is working fine. But when I tail the log, upstart is trying to restart the app every second due to that error.

I have tried to stop and start the app using upstart but to no avail. I am using [mupx](https://github.com/arunoda/meteor-up/tree/mupx) for deployment. Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue occurred because I was migrating from mup to mupx . With mupx, we do not have to use upstart.

That's why the app was running, even though it seemed that there was something wrong from the upstart log. I still don't know what caused upstart to complain about bcrypt.

Also, I don't think we have to pass `--architecture=os.linux.x86_6` manually, because [mup does it for you](https://github.com/arunoda/meteor-up#binary-npm-module-support).

See [Migrating from Meteor Up 0.x](https://github.com/arunoda/meteor-up/tree/mupx#migrating-from-meteor-up-0x) for information about migrating to mupx.